# Use Type to "as" keyword for get class object

Tags: c#

How can I use Type to "as" keyword for get class object

Here is an example :

```
class A
{
    public string Test { get; set; }

    public Type Type { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public string F { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new A();

        a.Type = typeof(B);

        var getB = (a.Type)Activator.CreateInstance(a.Type);

        getB.F = "Say something ...";
    }
}
```

This code won't work I am trying to get class object from Typeof

Comment: C# is a statically typed language - you must specify the actual type in a cast - it can't be a variable. Or, another way of looking at it, is that the compiler cannot determine the type of `getB` at compile-time so the code is illegal.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot declare object of type that is not known at compile time, as you tried to do here:

```
var getB = (a.Type)Activator.CreateInstance(a.Type);
```

This should work:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new A();

    A.Type = typeof(B);

    var getB = (B)Activator.CreateInstance(a.Type);

    getB.F = "Say something ...";
}
```

Or by using as operator:

```
var getB = Activator.CreateInstance(a.Type) as B;
```

Another alternative if you don't know the actual type at compile time is to use [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) keyword:

```
dynamic getB = Activator.CreateInstance(a.Type);
//it will compile but will throw runtime erros if getB does not have F property setter
getB.F = "Say something ...";
```